# Getting "AccessDeniedException" when using adminDeleteUser

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

When the node server is running locally, this seems to work fine.
But when then code is deployed on ec2 instance, I get:

"User: arn:aws:sts::XXXX:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-XXX is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminDeleteUser on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:ap-south-1:XXXX:userpool/XXXX"

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
At IAM, you can assign role( cognito full access permission ) to your EC2 instance. I am not familiar with Beanstalk. However, the approach might be same.

Option 2: (Not recommended)

Provide access key and secret key having enough permission at nodejs code. You can apply your local machine credentials to test it for now.

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that an IAM Role named `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` has been assigned to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Your code is apparently calling `AdminDeleteUser`. However, that IAM Role does not have permission to call `AdminDeleteUser`.

Therefore, you should probably **add that permission to the IAM Role**.

Presumably, when your code is running locally is it using credentials from your personal IAM User that likely has Admin rights. That is why it is running differently on the EC2 instance.